# Typescript - Blank Google Chart - Error: Row 0 has 2 columns, but must have 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-visualization

I want to draw google chart with dynamic data. For example, column can have 3 values or 2 values based on condition. Hence I assigned as below and in browser console getting error.

I can assign 0 for Array[2], but in Graph it is showing some data hence I do not want Array[2] if the condition failed.

Is there any workaround to achieve the same.

```
 this.mycolumnChart = [];
for (const value of this.myChartValue) 
{

const varArray = [];
    if(value.US > 0 && value.CHN > 0)
    {
    varArray[0] = 'Abc';
    varArray[1] = value.US;
    varArray[2] = value.CHN;
    }
    else if(value.US > 0)
    {
    varArray[0] = 'Abc';
    varArray[1] = value.US;
    }
    else
    {
    varArray[0] = 'Abc';
    varArray[1] = value.CHN;
    }
    this.mycolumnChart.push(varArray);
}
```

**Error: Row 0 has 2 columns, but must have 3**

Comment: It might not be it but you declared your const with the name `Array` which is a global object used in constructions of arrays (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Try changing the name of the variable to something else and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: @WojciechDynus - Sorry, that was an example. Now I have updated with the actual  code.

Comment: Can the third column be null or undefined instead of the "0" value you tried? Maybe then this will not show any results in the graph. Nevertheless, it looks that you will have to have 3 rows in each column anyway.

Comment: will you please share the code that creates the data table? -- are you using `arrayToDataTable` -- do you include column headings? etc...